# How to transfer input data in php using session

Tags: php, html

I working on the project and I need help with displaying what user typed in input on one page and display on the other page using session.

This is my code for page where user types his/her name:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="s2q2.php" name="s2n" method="POST">
        <p>Enter your name:</p>
        <input style="border: none; border-bottom: dashed; height: 50px; width:25%; margin-top: 45px; font-size: 35px;" type="text" script="sessionStorage.setItem('s2n');"><br>
        <button class="button" type="submit" style="vertical-align: center; background-color: #1e00ff; margin-top: 50px;" name="s2q1"><span>Next </span></button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code is transferring the variable using method POST to a site called s2q2.php. Can you also post this site?

Comment: Also, you reference [sessionStorage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem), but I don't think `input` elements have `script` attributes. What is that intended to do?

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) for sessions is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing but from my experience working with PHP here's how we `$_POST` data and make use of `$_SESSION` *the easy way*

EDIT : in your question we don't know whether you know how to use `session_start()` or not. We also don't know how the files and folders in your program are set up to give proper answer. But usually (well me) I create a `config.php` file which holds database information then I include that file in the header (`header.php`) because usually `header.php` is included everywhere in the program. I created file examples assuming you are using `mysqli`.

**config.php**

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
 define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'my_database_name');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
}

    // This tells the web browser that your content is encoded using UTF-8 
    // and that it should submit content back to you using UTF-8 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

    // This initializes a session.  Sessions are used to store information about 
    // a visitor from one web page visit to the next.  Unlike a cookie, the information is 
    // stored on the server-side and cannot be modified by the visitor.  However, 
    // note that in most cases sessions do still use cookies and require the visitor 
    // to have cookies enabled.  For more information about sessions: 
    // http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php 
    session_start(); 

    // Note that it is a good practice to NOT end your PHP files with a closing PHP tag. 
    // This prevents trailing newlines on the file from being included in your output, 
    // which can cause problems with redirecting users.
```

**header.php (include this file everywhere you need or else include config.php)**

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'); 
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);//handle php errors
 ob_start();//prevent header from being sent twice
 require_once('config.php');
```

**form**

```
require_once('header.php'); 

<form action="s2q2.php" method="POST">
    <p>Enter your name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <button type="submit" name="s2q1"><span>Next </span></button>
</form>
```

**s2q2.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['s2q1'])) {     // Retrieve form
    $name = $_POST['name'];      // retrieve data name
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;   // pass data in session
}
```

**Using `$_SESSION`**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['name'];
} else {
    //do something else;
}
```

Comment: You need to start the session before you can use it.

Comment: @Qirel: well it's not part of the question and if we need to show OP how to handle the whole process it's a bit out of scope and he /she should read documentation or ask a different question.

Comment: OP asked how to use sessions, and you can't use sessions before starting it - so I'd say that's very much within the scope of the question ;-)

Comment: @Qirel: I have edited my answer. Now it would be nice to actually hear back from OP :-)

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath! ;-) @Balloon

Comment: @Qirel : Ha not a chance `X-D`

Answer (score 0):

First, modify the form input to have a name :

I working on the project and I need help with displaying what user typed in input on one page and display on the other page using session.

This is my code for page where user types his/her name:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

     <form action="s2q2.php" name="s2n" method="POST">
         <p>Enter your name:</p>
         <input name="username" style="border: none; border-bottom: dashed; height: 50px; width:25%; margin-top: 45px; font-size: 35px;" type="text" script="sessionStorage.setItem('s2n');"><br>
         <button class="button" type="submit" style="vertical-align: center; background-color: #1e00ff; margin-top: 50px;" name="s2q1"><span>Next </span></button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

then, on s2q2.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
echo $_SESSION["username"] ;
?>
```

Comment: The elements ID won't be useful for anything to PHP - you need to use the input's name. You also need to use `session_start()`.

Comment: thnx Qirel, It should be name.

Answer (score 0):

First you create a session file called **session_start.php** that looks like this

```
 <?php
   session_start();
 ?>
```

then you just need to include it everywhere you want to have your session variables

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input Site</title>
    <style>
    .input1 {
            border: none;
            border-bottom: dashed;
            height: 50px; width:25%;
            margin-top: 45px;
            font-size: 35px;
           }
    .button1 {
            vertical-align: center;
            background-color: #1e00ff;
            margin-top: 50px;
           }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method"post">
<p>Enter your name:</p>
<input class="input1" type="text" name="nameInput"><br>
<button class="button1" type="submit" name="submitBut"><span>Next</span></button>
</form>

<?php 
// including the session file
require_once("session_start.php");

if (isset($_POST['submitBut'])) { 
 $_SESSION['nameInput'] = $_POST['nameInput'];
} 
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

then you create whatever site **whatever.php** and just have include your **session_start.php** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Whatever Site</title>
</head>
<body> 
<?php 
// including the session file
require_once("session_start.php");  
?>  
<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['nameInput'];?></strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `session_start()` shouldn't be after any output, it might not be started if it is - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php - and I honestly see no reason why to have it in a separate file if that's all it does. (And nitpicking: `require` isn't a function) ;-)

Comment: there is no output after session_start() in session_start.php.

Comment: But there is before you use it. You have HTML before including the file.

Comment: There is no html in session_start.php

Comment: That's right - but there is output before you require that file, and so there becomes output before the session call. And might I ask why you have it in a separate file, that does nothing more than start the session? Seems like more work than it saves to me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, lets see another example ( need to sanitize $name before output! )

```
<?php
    $name = isset($_SESSION['key_whatever']) ? $_SESSION['key_whatever'] :null;
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="s2q2.php" method="POST">
            <p>Enter your name:</p>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$name?>">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="s2q1"><span>Next </span></button>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>





/*

    on submit if youre not using any rewrite rules -> s2q2.php will be compiled and executed

        -------s2q2.php-------
*/
<?php    
     session_start();   <--- need to be set
     $_SESSION['key_whatever'] = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;

?>
```